# Combine columns from one data frame into new data frame, and filter

Tags: r

```
Material    DocDate    Name  Address    Unit    Price
1258486   3/17/2017   FEHLIG BROS BOX    asd     8.95
1258486   5/11/2017   FEHLIG BROS BOX    asd     9.5
1258486   12/11/2017  FEHLIG BROS_BOX    asd     10.5
1250000   12/20/2017  Krones ALPHA       afg     11.5
```

I have a above data frame. I need to frame like below based on dates(3/17/2017) appears first. So i need below output

```
Material         Name/address/Unit Price
1258486     FEHLIG BROS BOX/asd/8.95/9.5/10.5
1250000     Krones/ALPHA/afg/11.5
```

Comment: Is the question about producing a new data frame that combines name/address/unit/price into one field? `paste(Name, Address, Unit, Price, sep = "/")` should help.  Do you want just the first row, or perhaps some sorting by date?

Comment: @ Jon spring. Yes your right.

Comment: I would suggest to include more cases (rows) since there could be many possible answers. And also, better to exclude '\' and spaces in the name of variable of your data frame.

Comment: While it is OK to edit in order to remove information you consider confidential while leaving your question (and the answers) in understandable condition, you need to do so with care, so that you don't destroy the value of the question and answers. If it is truly confidential information, and the question/answers can still have value without it, once you have made the edits you can, then you can flag for moderator attention to ask for the old version(s) to be redacted (i.e. actually removed so that they are no longer visible to those looking at the edit history).

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: Editing Questions to improve them (e.g. clarification, etc.) *is encouraged*. However, editing a Question to change it such that it invalidates an Answer, is against policy on Stack Overflow. Your edits here did so. The policy is that other users should proactively revert such changes. I have done so here. You *are encouraged to [ask a new Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)*, perhaps with a link to this one for additional context. We want to help, but your new/additional issue needs to be a new Question.

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table` you can try

```
df <- read.table(stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE,
                 text ="Material DocDate Name  Address Unit  Price
                 1258486   3/17/2017  FEHLIG BROS_BOX     asd     8.95
                 1258486   5/11/2017  FEHLIG BROS_BOX     asd     9.5
                 1258486   12/11/2017  FEHLIG BROS_BOX    asd     10.5
                 1250000   12/20/2017  Krones ALPHA       afg     11.5
                 ")
df$DocDate <- as.Date(df$DocDate,'%m/%d/%Y')
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,.(newVar = paste(Name, Address, Unit, paste(.SD$Price,collapse = "/"), sep = "/") )
          ,by = Material][,.(newVar = newVar[1]), Material]

#returns
   Material                            newVar
1:  1258486 FEHLIG/BROS_BOX/asd/8.95/9.5/10.5
2:  1250000             Krones/ALPHA/afg/11.5
```

Comment: I have edited the answer considering this and your new data

Comment: @Makyen Thank you so much for bringing back my solution, I mistakenly click approve in last edit.

Comment: @Makyen Yes,  I thought I was approving the rejection, however immediately i checked it was his edit what i approved.Thank you again. I just noticed also OP changed the initial data, so sad is playing games with questions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative using `dplyr`. First the sample data:

```
data <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                   Material   = c(1258486L, 1258486L),
                   DocDate    = c("3/17/2017", "5/11/2017"),
                   Name       = c("FEHLIG BROS BOX", "FEHLIG BROS BOX"),
                   Address    = c("asd", "asd"),
                   Unit_Price = c(8.95, 9.5))
```

And then here are one set of steps to get your answer. (BTW, I believe all the solutions provided so far would give you multiple rows of output if there are multiple `Material` rows that share the same "earliest date." You might want another term like `Unit_Price == min(Unit_Price)` inside the `filter` if there's a tie-breaker that makes sense here.)

```
library(dplyr)
output <- data %>%

  # convert DocDate to a date
  mutate(DocDate = as.Date(DocDate,'%m/%d/%Y')) %>%

  # For each Material...
  group_by(Material) %>% 

  # just keep the line(s) with the first date...
  filter(DocDate == min(DocDate)) %>% ungroup() %>% 

  # and combine fields
  mutate(`Name/address/Unit Price` = paste(Name, Address, Unit_Price, sep = "/")) %>%

  # just the requested columns
  select(Material, `Name/address/Unit Price`)

output
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  Material `Name/address/Unit Price`
     <int> <chr>                    
1  1258486 FEHLIG BROS BOX/asd/8.95
```

(EDIT: fixed typos in code)

Answer (score 0):

A complete edit, based on changes to your question:

```
# create example data (notice this differs slightly from your table above)
df <- read.csv(stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE,
                 text ="Material, DocDate, Name, Address, UnitPrice
                        1258486, 3/17/2017, FEHLIG BROS BOX, asd, 8.95
                        1258486, 5/11/2017, FEHLIG BROS BOX, asd, 9.50
                        1258486, 12/11/2017, FEHLIG BROS_BOX, asd, 10.5
                        1250000, 12/20/2017, Krones ALPHA, afg, 11.5")

# let's use data.table
library(data.table)
df_orig <- as.data.table(df)
df_orig[ , DocDate := as.Date(DocDate,format="%m/%d/%Y")][order(DocDate)]

# create one string per Name-Material pair
df_intermed <- df_orig[ , .(newvar = paste(Name[1], Address[1], paste(UnitPrice, collapse="/"), sep="/")), by=.(Material, Name)]

# aggregate those strings across Names, so one row per Material
df_final <- df_intermed[ , .(newvar = paste(newvar, collapse=",")), by=Material]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179873/discussion-on-answer-by-dan-y-combine-columns-from-one-data-frame-into-new-data).

Comment: hi Dan, Still the sort of date is not working. Still getting <NA> in the date